# How to install Nokia_X series sdk in eclipse Adt Bundle

Tags: android, sdk, nokiax

I have Eclipse & Android sdk adt bundle. Now I need to  install Nokia_X series sdk with eclipse. How to install Nokia_X sdk. I have tried many times.  But it shows error message like "unable to install".

Comment: see this link and install nokia sdk http://developer.nokia.com/nokia-x/downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try with the instructions given in: http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/getting-started/environment-setup.html

If so, which step did you get into before you got this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you also tried by using the downloadable SDK plugin, instead of the Eclipse add-on site?

http://developer.nokia.com/nokia-x/downloads